# PHP CodeIgniter Authorization of Features via URI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authorization

I am designing a web application that is heavy reliant on database tables/records and have already designed the login system. As it stands, the login system creates an element in the session to verify that the user is logged on. This works fine.

However, as I've been coding my application--I have found a constant need to check that my users are authorized to perform certain actions.

For example--I have a feature which allows users to edit their profile at www.mywebsite/account/edit/1 -> 1 being the Id. In terms of future scalability, is it practical to perform a database query to check that the current logged in user has access to edit their information after arriving at that URL?
My concern, of course, is that someone would just put in a random Id to edit another account.

I have also thought about creating a form between every transition to post this data, yet that comes with a load of limitations itself.

I was wondering if anyone had hit the same problems and found an overall solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a concern that everyone addresses at some point or another. The way I see it, you're really asking a couple of questions:

1. How do I make sure a user is authorized to access something? and
2. Is checking the database every single time really the best way to do it?

With respect to the first question: the approach you're taking is probably the only realistic one. It boils down to this: whenever a user needs to do something, your application needs to check *something* to see if they're allowed to do it. What is that something? It's called an Access Control List (ACL).

You *could* hard code the ACL in your application, but that's a really bad idea. So that means you have to store the details of an ACL somewhere. And when we start talking about storing something in our applications, the obvious answer is (almost) always in the database.

Which leads to the second question... a quick check of the database to see if a user has access is generally not going to be a huge bottleneck, provided your database design is sensible. You're going to be doing something like `SELECT key FROM acl WHERE key='something' AND user_id='current user ID';` and checking to make sure you get at least one result. It's going to add a little overhead to your application, but what's the alternative? Some sort of hard coded ACL? Loading the full ACL for your application and searching it for the key and user ID in your PHP code?

If you're really concerned about the overhead involved with your ACL stored in MySQL, you could look at some of the other databases like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) which should be faster for simple key/value pair lookups (note that I've looked at both MongoDB & CouchDB, but not used either in applications), but I think you'll find that, for most applications, doing it in MySQL should work just fine.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you to took answer my questions in length--this was exactly what I was looking for. I will be researching MySQL ACL designs and try to implement this into my application. Thank you Kryten!